# How to look up the lowest price for any of a list of substitutes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find the lowest price for any item in a group of substitutable products. My thought was to use an array formula but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    A      B      C      D    E
1   Item   Site1  Site2       Valid
2   one           1.5         one
3   two    2                  two
4   three         1           four
5   four   7      8     
6   five   1            
7                   
8   Best   0      1.5
```

The array formula in B8 is:

```
{=MIN(INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH($E$2:$E$4,$A$2:$A$6,0)))}
```

It's working for Site 2, but only because the `MATCH` part of the formula only picks up the first item from the list of valid items, rather than the whole array as I had expected.

Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure right now but certain commands break if a value is missing. So you might be having issues because you got empty cells in the list for `Site1` and `Site2`.

Comment: No, that's not it. The issue is definitely that the `MATCH` part of the formula is only picking up `one` from the array `{one, two, four}`. I've tested filling in other values and it always returns the value in the `one` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the approach of your array formula, but this formula works:
`=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$E$2:$E$4,0))*ISNUMBER(B$2:B$6),B$2:B$6,""))`

Where:

- `ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$E$2:$E$4,0))` checks whether item is included in list of valid items
- `ISNUMBER(B$2:B$6)` checks whether current item has a price or it's empty (otherwise Excel would automatically convert `blank` to `0`)

[image]

Comment: I was just guessing at what might work if I'm honest. Yours works perfectly though